# react input checkboxes - not toggling with change in state

Tags: arrays, reactjs, input, checkbox, state

I'm having trouble getting a group of checkboxes to toggle with changes in state. I'm rendering the checkboxes using array.map and returning input elements.

It looks like my handleUpdateCheck function updates state appropriately, but the DOM does not re-render.

```
const [checked, updateChecked] = useState([true, true, true, false, false]);

function handleUpdateChecked(index) {
    let newArr = checked;
    newArr[index] = !checked[index]
    updateChecked(newArr);
}

checked.map((box, index) => {
    return (
        <input
            key={index}
            type='checkbox'
            checked={checked[index]}
            onChange ={() => handleUpdateChecked(index)}
        />
    )
})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue you're hitting is that you're inadvertently modifying state. One way to prevent this from happening is to create a shallow copy of the `checked` array using the spread operator.

```
const [checked, updateChecked] = useState([true, true, true, false, false]);

function handleUpdateChecked(index) {
    let newArr = [...checked];
    newArr[index] = !checked[index]
    updateChecked(newArr);
}

checked.map((box, index) => {
    return (
        <input
            key={index}
            type='checkbox'
            checked={checked[index]}
            onChange ={() => handleUpdateChecked(index)}
        />
    )
})
```